# How to move button through dialog using mfc application

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am beginner and want to move button in such away that i click on a button and that moves to the coordinates that i have given statically. so what class i have to use and in which way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use the [MoveWindow()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5bc5w1zz%28v=vs.10%29.aspx) method of your [CButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yf1wax6c%28v=vs.10%29.aspx) as:

```
m_btnDoSomething.MoveWindow(CRect(0, 0, 20, 20));
```

(the rectangle is in client coordinates)